Multiple PCB based on one schematic in Altium Designer
I want to create few versions of PCB layout based on one schematic. Difference in those versions is different position of connector.
How can I do that in Altium Designer?

One option would be to put all of the possible connector positions into the design and then populate only the one you need for a given assembly. That's what Design Variants are for.
But if you really want several different PCB layouts based on a common schematic diagram, you can simply create a different PCB file in your project for each one, all based on the same schematic file.

You do not need to copy any schematic. Only one schematic is needed, with multiple pcb files.

@MrGerber: Thanks, I've added that to my answer.

Nice. You probably want to complete layout on one and then copy the PCB to other files and make modifications to the copies. Confirmed that multiple PCB files are individually and selectively updated from the schematic when they are in the tree.

You can create different PCB files in the same project, But you have to rearrange the layout two times and Component placement files are different in both cases, So keep that in mind. Two different Gerbers, BOM, CPL can be generated in this case with single schema.
